# Match fitted values from `lm()` with a data frame in case of `NA` values

Tags: r, merge, lm

This must be a really trivial question but I'm struggeling to get a solution. Here is my problem:

**this works**

```
#I run a simple regression
 data(mtcars)
 dataf <- mtcars
 summary(fit1 <- lm(mpg ~ wt,  data=dataf))

#Then I merge the fitted values with the data frame
 dataf$fit <- fitted(fit1)
```

**This (of course) doesn't work**

```
 dataf[2,]<-NA
 summary(fit2 <- lm(mpg ~ wt,  data=dataf))
#of course the NA value reduces my lm output
 dataf$fit2 <- fitted(fit2)

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "fit2", value = c(23.3189679389035,  : 
replacement has 31 rows, data has 32
```

but how do I geht the second example to work? I tried a solution via the `row.names` in `model.matrix()` but this does not work when I include certain factors in my regression (this has been reported as a [bug](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=14992) if I understand this correctly). Thank you for your kind help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some search I think I found an alternative

```
dataf[2,]<-NA
summary(fit2 <- lm(mpg ~ wt,  data=dataf, na.action="na.exclude"))
dataf$fit2 <- fitted(fit2)
```

should do the trick. right?

Answer (score 4):

```
dataf$fit2 <- NA
dataf$fit2[!is.na(dataf$wt)] <- fitted(fit2)
```